# printing multiple href with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to print out the hyperlinks but get the "none" or "<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8b0ee7c2cf785e0a32ce3a7e4cffee50", element="a8d14f16-2431-4c05-bf93-6c92aad390ca")>". I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.autotempest.com/results?make=chevrolet&zip=72032&radius=25"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
driver.minimize_window()

links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
"result-wrap")))
for link in links:
    link.get_attribute("href")
    print (link)

driver.quit()
```

Anyone care to educate me?

Comment: `get_attribute` RETURNS the value, which you then throw away.  You want `print(link.get_attribute("href"))`.  You probably want to make sure the `link` is valid before doing that, as in `if link:`.

Comment: this returns "none" for all

Comment: Yes, because the only elements with class "result-wrap" are `<div>`s, which do not have `href` attributes.  There are no `<a>` tags with that class.  You're looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was afraid that may be it. What should I be calling on then?

Comment: I think the answer told you that.  You needed to be looking for `<a>` tags, not `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues:

1. You were printing the `link` element instead of the "href". Updated code:

   ```
   for link in links:
       print (link.get_attribute("href"))
   ```
2. Turns out your locator for the links isn't correct. You were using the class name, "result-wrap", which finds a DIV instead of the descendant A tag. A switch to the CSS selector `.result-wrap .listing-title > a` fixes that.
3. You were waiting for presence of the elements. Presence just means that the elements are in the DOM, not that they are visible/interactable. I switched the wait to visible.

The final updated code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Set up the Chrome driver and maximize the window
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

# Navigate to the URL
url = "https://www.autotempest.com/results?make=chevrolet&zip=72032&radius=25"
driver.get(url)

links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".result-wrap .listing-title > a")))
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

which prints all the URLs like

```
https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listing/1G1ZD5ST7JF128033/?referrer_id=autotempest
...
```

---

FYI... Selenium v4.6+ now comes with DriverManager which will manage driver installs, etc. So, this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

becomes

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Just delete any existing `chromedriver.exe`s on your box and you should be good.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up

Comment: @Michael I've added the updated locator. The code is working now.

Comment: you are literally a godsend. I could not find any tutorial on what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To print out the hyperlinks in your code, you need to use the get_attribute() method to retrieve the href attribute of each link and print it to the console. Here's an updated version of your code that should do what you want:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.autotempest.com/results?make=chevrolet&zip=72032&radius=25"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
driver.minimize_window()

links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
"result-wrap")))
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)

driver.quit()
```

This code will print out the href attribute of each link to the console. If you want to remove any None values, you can add a check to see if the href is None before printing it:

```
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    if href is not None:
        print(href)
```

This will only print out the href if it is not None.

Comment: Using the code provided, it only returns none, I know the href if under that class. Doing the if statement provides nothing in the console